# Why one curve is up and other one is below for the same or different compound nucleus and why the curve shape is like this?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, potential-energy, nuclear-engineering

[image: the plot is potential vs deformation, I want to know why there is difference between two potential vs deformation curves for the same and different compound nucleus and why the shape is like that.]

the plot is potential vs deformation, I want to know why there is difference between two potential vs deformation curves for the same and different compound nucleus and why the shape is like that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why we are getting these curves, not a straight line or something else. And what is the meaning of these curves